# Changing TFS build drop location for specific solutions

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have two solutions within a single build. Our current solutions to build look like this:

`<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Main/Services/Solution1.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>`

`<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Main/Web/Solution2.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>`

Having them this way, the output will be dropped under the \$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Releases folder. My objective is that the output files for each solution be dropped in different drop folders. Example. Solution1.sln drop location is to be \$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Releases\Services.

How can I specify the solution to build properties to achieve this result? I have tried using the following property without success as several output files are not copied to the specified output drop location:

`<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Main/Services/Solution1.sln">
        <Targets></Targets>
        <Properties>OutDir=$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Services\</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>`

EDIT: We are currently using TFS2010 but these are our old TFS2008 builds that use the upgrade template

Comment: We use the OutDir property. Maybe some of your files aren't marked as "Copy Local"?

`<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)\myFooSolution.sln">
      <Properties>OutDir=$(OutDir)\FooFolder\</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>`

Comment: @Alicia thanks for that. After replacing OutDir=$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Services\ with OutDir=$(OutDir)\FooFolder\
it started working and all our executables and binaries are being built properly. Can you add it as an answer so I can promote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the OutDir property. Maybe some of your files aren't marked as "Copy Local"?

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)\myFooSolution.sln"> 
<Properties>OutDir=$(OutDir)\FooFolder\</Properties> 
</SolutionToBuild>
```